# MediaStreamRecorder stops recording when browser window minimized

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, streaming, webrtc

I am using [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder/blob/master/MediaStreamRecorder.js) which follows the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) for recording cross-browser audio and video streams.

The problem that I am facing is that the `MediaStreamRecorder` stops firing its `ondataavailable` event whenever the browser window is minimized. Once you minimized it stops triggering the `ondataavailable` event and doesn't fire even if I comeback to the same windows unless or until I stops the recording and restart it again.

It doesn't give any exception in the browser console. Everything works fine until you minimizes the browser window. Once you did that, it stops executing the code inside the function that executes on `ondataavailable` event.

```
var ws;

function start() {

    ws = new WebSocket("wss://xyz/");

    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log("WebSocket has been opened!");
    };

    ws.onmessage = function (message) {
        console.log("A messsage is received from WebSocket Server.", message);
    };

    ws.onclose = function (e) {
        console.log('WebSocket is closed. Reconnection will be attempted in 5 second.', e.reason);
        setTimeout(function () {
            start();
        }, 5000);
    };

    ws.onerror = function (err) {
        console.error('WebSocket encountered an error: ', err.message, 'Closing WebSocket');
        ws.close();
    };

}

start();


function startRecording(localStream, remoteStream) {

    if (localStream != null && remoteStream != null) {

        multiStreamRecorder = new MultiStreamRecorder([localStream, remoteStream], "video/webm");
        multiStreamRecorder.mimeType = "video/webm";

        multiStreamRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {

            console.log("sending blob to websocket server");
            ws.send(blob);

        };

        multiStreamRecorder.start(1500);

    }
    else{
        console.error("One or more streams are null.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was reported only in google chrome and it happened only in a case of a video call. It was working perfectly fine in Mozilla Firefox which ensured me that, the problem is not in my code. And later when I updated my Google Chrome, everything started working perfectly fine.

---

**Detailed Answer:**

I did a lot of research and after testing my code in Mozilla Firefox I concluded that it doesn't have to do anything with my code. I went to the chrome settings to check the chromes version and it was **57.0.2987.133**.

[image]

As soon as I hit the about section of chrome, it started updating and finished updating to the version **58.0.3029.110**

[image]

After the update everything started working perfectly. And since then my chrome is updated few times but didn't get in to the same problem again. So it proved that it was a bug in *Google Chrome*.

Currently I'm running my application on **Google Chrome 59.0.3071.115**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can console.log the `MediaRecorder.state` which will tell you the state of MediaRecorder.state which I bet is "inactive" when the browser is minimized.  If so then more than likely `MediaRecorder.stop()` is automatically called by the browser thus stoping your recording.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/stop